# I can't set my VS 2019 language into C++17

Tags: c++, visual-studio

If i try setting the language to C++17 in the solution explorer property settings, I end up seeing that there is 2 errors.

The first one says:

> Error     Element  has an invalid value of
> "/std:c++17". pls C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   636

And the second one says:

> Error MSB6011 Invalid parameters passed to the
> Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL task. pls C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   636

What do I do? I tryed everything, but nothing works. Here i found a similar question, and someone said to set "platforms" to "all platforms", but it didn't work.

Comment: This may be a question to ask at the Microsoft Forums.

Comment: Make sure you're setting it for the properties of the same configuration (Release|Debug) and platform (Win32|x64), that you're trying to build.

Comment: Is your project a pure-C++ project, or a C++-CLR one?

Comment: Have you already tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160#to-set-this-compiler-option-in-the-visual-studio-development-environment)?

Comment: @Cub0n0ut If you create a new project, will you encounter the same error? If so, I suggest you could try to reinstall the Desktop development with C++. If not, it may be related to your project. And could you please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've got all the necessary components installed. I've got the following stuff installed. You might not need all of them, but it's worth a try.

[image: VS2019 C++ components]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all of your support! I managed to solve this problem. What happened was that I accidentally typed the wrong option. Thank you for your answers though.